# Can't list containers with manager node "Reachable", only with "Leader"

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-container

I worked with https://labs.play-with-docker.com.

I created a new service in one of the managers (not the leader):

```
docker service create --name example nginx
```

When I ran:

```
docker container ls
```

It didn't show me the containers:
[image]

But when I ran the same command on the manager **leader** node, it did:
[image]

Any explanation why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a service that is replicated only once (one container), if you want a global service (a container in each VM) you have to add `--mode global` flag to you `docker service create` command, by the way you take a look at `--replicas` flag too : https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/

Comment: Oh right ! thanks. I created a service with `docker service create --replicas 3 --name example nginx` and now I see it in all the nodes.